# Sync Thunderbird configs across computers

Tags: sync, thunderbird

I sync my thunderbird profile folder with owncloud so that I can have the same configs across all my computers.

Because of the size of the folder, data sometimes get corrupted or version conflict..

Does anyone have a better solution?

The important part I would like to sync is mail accounts config and calendars, mails can sync naturally by imap.

Comment: Couldn't you just exclude the imap mail storage (`~/.thunderbird/<profile>.default/ImapMail`) from your backups?

Comment: @Glutanimate that could be a plan B, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

the best way I've found to sync Thunderbirds settings, even mail boxes across machines is by using TEBE
http://www.customsoftwareconsult.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=2957

It's an off branch of FEBE (firefox) but since now Firefox has its own sync, FEBE became less, it's still great for Offline Backup purposes.

However FEBE is still the main tool I use to keep my Thunderbird settings across machines, since Thunderbird does not yet have a online sync tool built-in as Firefox does.

and TEBE has BOX.net sync option, so you can pick it up from another computer via TEBE by connecting to the same account, after each scheduled backup, or manual backup.

You can also specify what to backup and what to skip.